# Openinviter not importing contacts of Hotmail using php

Tags: php, javascript

I am using open-inviter technology for importing contacts from gmail, yahoo and hot-mail.

All these were working well last month, but now this app is unable to import contacts from hotmail, may be hot-mail changed its terms and conditions.

Even I am facing some problems for importing contacts with yahoo, only for some specific email-id's.

Even I tried to import from http://svetlozar.net/address-book-importer-demo.html, with these same email-id's and its showing the same error message "Login Failed. Please Check Your Email-Id and Password you have provided".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which OpenInviter version are you using...?

Comment: Hi sudhir, I was using version 1.7.6 at my site. But now i used newer version 1.9.6 at demo http://www.21flats.com/beta_importer/OpenInviter_v_1.9.6/example.php , but it's also showing the same problem for both hotmail as well as yahoo..

Answer (score 2):

Using Open Invitor and  http://svetlozar.net , do contact grabbing is againt of terms and condition of hotmail.dont do this.hotmail doesnt provide email id of friend,it provide hashes of email id.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#contact